# expected class,delegate,enum,interface or struct

Tags: c#, class

I am writing a class. I have encountered the problem in the title.
Here is the code:

```
class delivery
{
    private string strDeliveryName;
    private string strDeliveryAddress;
    private string strDeliveryDay;
    private string strDeliveryTime;
    private string strDeliveryMeal;
    private string strDeliveryInstructions;
    private string strDeliveryStatus;
}
public delivery(string deliveryName, string deliveryAddress, string deliveryDay, string deliveryTime, string deliveryMeal, string deliveryInstructions, string deliveryStatus)
    {
        strDeliveryName = deliveryName;
        strDeliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;
        strDeliveryDay = deliveryDay;
        strDeliveryTime = deliveryTime;
        strDeliveryMeal = deliveryMeal;
        strDeliveryInstructions = deliveryInstructions;
        strDeliveryStatus = deliveryStatus;
    }
```

I get the error on the public delivery, any idea why?

Comment: Hungarian notation is frowned upon.

Comment: Am now getting an error saying Method must have a return type?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your constructor should be within the brackets of the class definition. On an unrelated note, the convention is to capitalize the first letter of class names.

Comment: Fixed, thanks.
I understand about the class names and will update accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor code is not inside the class. Move it inside and all should be fine. :-)

Comment: Is it working now?  If not, please edit your question and show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question (in the comment), you need to change the name of the constructor to match the name of the class.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because you have declared the function outside of the `main` class.  You should insert your code inside the `main` class.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because I accidentally missed an open brace in code above where the error occurred. This meant the class ended prematurely. So if you get this error maybe check that your braces are correct.